# 12.04 internal error ( Sorry Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error )

Tags: 12.04

I am running 12.04 LTS. I have been since its release. But all of a sudden my machine now take 5/6 minutes to boot up. I do not have sound anymore, where pulse audio was listed now reads dummy output. Also all USBs have stopped working and CD/DVD drives (X2). Also now my built in MMC card reader is not working.

My machine is an old Packard bell Imedia S1839, Intel duo core processor with 4GB RAM X2 SATA drives 1 X 1TB 1X 320GB. Ubuntu worked really well up to 5 days ago. I don't want to wipe everything off and try to reinstall as I can't back up data.

Any ideas please?

Comment: the error is   executable path:  /usr/lib/gnome-disk-utility/gdu-notification-daemon.      problem : crash  title: gdu-notification-daemon crashed with SIGABRT in raise ()   Apport version: 2.0.1-0ubuntu 12  i hope this helps,regards mike.

Comment: Solved it. Deleted unity, restarted computer and reinstalled unity, then ran software updater.only problem now is, computer detects on board sound card not added sound card. head set only works in analogue and not stereo.